# importing mysql database using mamp, phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, mamp, database-restore

I am trying to copy a MyIsam dataBase from my a remote server to my local machine for testing.   I am using phpMyAdmin on the remote server.  I select the database and then export. When I try to import (using mamp, phMyAdmin) I get the following error message
    Error
    SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `assignments` (
`uid` int( 11 ) default NULL ,
`rid` int( 11 ) default NULL ,
`semester` varchar( 255 ) default NULL ,
`year` int( 11 ) default NULL
) TYPE = MYISAM ;

MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax
to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 6
```

Please Help!

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the trick proposed by Reza (Type=InnoDB) but I use MAMP on local machines and it can support either InnoDB/MyISAM… Which version of MAMP do you use ? (I use the free one)

Comment: Simply remove the 'TYPE = MYISAM ;' part (but leave the ending bracket ) ).
Select your database in phpMyAdmin, click on SQL, and copy paste the code. This should create the table with default type, which is usually MyISAM.

Comment: Tried removing all the Type=myisam  calls from the .sql eport file but now the import fails for another syntax based error.  
Could it have anything to do with the fact tat I'm trying to export from  mySql server version 5.0.77-log   into mySql server verson 5.5.9?

Comment: I would assume newer mysql versions are backward compatible (at least to the last major version). After you removed myisam, did you change it to innodb? From your previous comment it seems like it defaults to myisam anyways unless you override it. what was the new error message?

Comment: OK I got a correct answer :
Try replacing 'TYPE = MYISAM' by 'ENGINE = MYISAM'.
This is the correct syntax and should do it :)

Comment: You rock! Changing TYPE=MYISAM to ENGINE=MYISAM Totally worked.  I wonder why my dump file had TYPE as opposed to ENGINE

Comment: I also found a useful (understandable) pros and cons of MyISAM vs InnoDB here [link]http://linuxers.org/howto/myisam-or-innodb-mysql-engine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your local database doesn't support MyISAM type? Does it have to be MyISAM? You can try changing it to 'TYPE=InnoDB' in the sql dump text file

Comment: The database that I am trying to import is a myISAM,  I'm not sure if that means that the database I'm iporting to has to be myISAM as well.   I did change the my.cnf,  "default-storage-engine = MyISAM"  and verified from the terminal that it is defaulted to myISAM.

Comment: The destination doesn't need to be MyISAM as well, as I have imported other isam dbs into inno before. If in the db dump file, at the end of create table statements you add type=InnoDB to overcome this problem if you don't care about the db type

Comment: Tried changing all the type=MyISAM to innoDB ,  still didn't work