# 1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM

Tags: mysql, syntax

Here is my error(if you need any more info just ask)-
Error
SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE dave_bannedwords(

id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
word VARCHAR( 60 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '',
PRIMARY KEY ( id ) ,
KEY id( id )
) TYPE = MYISAM ;
```

MySQL said:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 6

Comment: the Key (id) is also redundant.  it will already be indexed because of the primary key

Answer (score 75, accepted):

As documented under [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html):

> **Note**
>   The older `TYPE` option was synonymous with `ENGINE`. `TYPE` was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5. *When upgrading to MySQL 5.5 or later, you must convert existing applications that rely on `TYPE` to use `ENGINE` instead.*

Therefore, you want:

```
CREATE TABLE dave_bannedwords(
  id   INT(11)     NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  word VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  KEY id(id) -- this is superfluous in the presence of your PK, ergo unnecessary
) ENGINE = MyISAM ;
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Type used to be a synonym of ENGINE but it was deprecated in 4.0 and removed in 5.5.

Comment: Thanks for all your help :) but I think the whole mysql database is like that :(

Comment: @eggyal 
#1060 - Duplicate column name 'id'

Comment: @NicholasMcLovinzRothapfel: Excuse me?

Answer (score 0):

**A complementary note about `CREATE TABLE .. TYPE=""` syntax in SQL dump files**

TLDR: If you still get `CREATE TABLE ... TYPE="..."` statements in SQL dump files generated by third party tools, it most certainly indicates that your server is configured to use a default `sqlmode` of `MYSQL40` or `MYSQL323`.

**Long story**

As it was said by others, the `TYPE` argument to `CREATE TABLE` has been deprecated for a long time in MySQL. `mysqldump` correctly uses the `ENGINE` argument, unless you specifically ask it to generate a backward compatible dump (for example using `--compatible=mysql40` in versions of `mysqldump` up to 5.7).

However, many external SQL dump tools (for example, those integrated in MySQL clients such as phpmyadmin, Navicat and DBVisualizer, as well as those used by external automated backup services such as iControlWP) are not specifically aware of this change, and instead rely on the `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` command to provide table creation statements for each tables (and just to it make it clear: this is actually a good thing). However, the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` will actually produce outdated syntax, including the `TYPE` argument, if the `sqlmode` variable is set to `MYSQL40` or `MYSQL323`.

Therefore, if you still get `CREATE TABLE ... TYPE="..."` statements in SQL dump files generated by third party tools, it most certainly indicates that your server is configured to use a default `sqlmode` of `MYSQL40` or `MYSQL323`.

These `sqlmode`s basically configure MySQL to retain some backward compatible behaviours, and using them by default was largely recommended a few years ago. It is however highly improbable that you still have any code that wouldn't work correctly without these modes. Anyway, `MYSQL40`, `MYSQL323` and several other similar `sqlmode`s have themselves been deprecated and are not supported in MySQL 8.0 and higher.

If your server is still configured with these `sqlmode`s and you are worried that some legacy program might fail if you change these, then one possibility is to set the `sqlmode` locally for that program, by executing `SET SESSION sql_mode = 'MYSQL40';` immediately after connection. Note that this should only be considered as a temporary patch, and will not work in MySQL 8.0 and higher.

A more future-proof solution that do not involve rewriting your SQL queries would be to determine exactly which compatibility features need to be enable, and to enable only those, on a per-program basis (as described previously). The default `sqlmode` (that is, in server's configuration) should ideally be left unset (which will use official MySQL defaults for your current version). The full list of `sqlmode` (as of MySQL 5.7) is described here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html.

Answer (score -2):

```
CREATE TABLE `admnih` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `asim` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `brid` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `rwtbah` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `esmmwkeh` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `mrwr` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `tid` int(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  `alksmfialdlil` int(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  `tariktsjil` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `aimwke` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `twkie` text NOT NULL,
  `rwtbahkasah` int(255) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? The name of the table in the question is `dave_bannedwords`, not `admnih`.

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT Email, COUNT(*)
FROM user_log    
WHILE Email IS NOT NULL    
GROUP BY Email    
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1    
ORDER BY UpdateDate DESC
```

> MySQL said: Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 36

---

Which correction below:

```
CREATE TABLE users_online (
  ip varchar(15) NOT NULL default '',
  time int(11) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (ip),
  UNIQUE KEY id (ip),
  KEY id_2 (ip)
  TYPE=MyISAM;
)
#                           
# Data untuk tabel `users_online`
#

INSERT INTO users_online VALUES ('127.0.0.1', 1158666872);
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? The name of the table in the question is `dave_bannedwords`, not `users_online`.

Answer (score -2):

Try the below query

```
CREATE TABLE card_types (
  card_type_id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (card_type_id),
) ENGINE = MyISAM ;
```

Comment: Is this an answer to the question? The name of the table in the question is `dave_bannedwords`, not `card_types`.