# Can anyone find the error error in sql syntax

Tags: mysql, ddl

Can someone tell me what wrong with this code

Table structure for table `epay_area_list`

```
CREATE TABLE epay_area_list(
   id tinyint( 3 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   titlechar( 30 ) NOT NULL default '',
   parent tinyint( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
   akey bigint( 20 ) NOT NULL default '0',
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) TYPE = 'MyISAM';
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'TYPE='MyISAM'' at line 23

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Should `titlechar( 30 )` be `title char( 30 )`?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: should there be more tables that that

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a space between `title` and its datatype `char( 30 )`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS epay_area_list (
   id tinyint( 3 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   title char( 30 ) NOT NULL default '', -- ADDED SPACE HERE
   parent tinyint( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
   akey bigint( 20 ) NOT NULL default '0',
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) TYPE = 'MyISAM';
```

Comment: # Host: localhost
# Generation Time: December 5, 2003, 10:03 am
# Server version: 3.23.41
# PHP Version: 4.2.2
# Database : `solarpay`
# --------------------------------------------------------
#
# Table structure for table `epay_area_list`
CREATE TABLE epay_area_list(
id tinyint( 3 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
titlechar( 30 ) NOT NULL default '',
parent tinyint( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
akey bigint( 20 ) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE = 'MyISAM';

MySQL said: Documentation
#1050 - Table 'epay_area_list' already exists

Comment: @user1786563 if the table already exists, drop it first! `drop table epay_area_list;`

Comment: @Bohemian you may not want to drop the table first. It does make it easier to test, but in production it can be a dangerous thing. If the table already exists and you try to create it, then that is an error case.

Comment: @user1786563 I added `IF NOT EXISTS` - that should please everyone

Comment: @RyanGates I added `IF NOT EXISTS` - that should please everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE epay_area_list(
   id tinyint( 3 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
   title char( 30 ) NOT NULL default '',
   parent tinyint( 4 ) NOT NULL default '0',
   akey bigint( 20 ) NOT NULL default '0',
   PRIMARY KEY ( id )
) ENGINE = 'MyISAM';
```

1. You were missing the space between `title` and `char`
2. You needed to use `ENGINE` not `TYPE` at the end

Comment: phpMyAdmin MySQL-Dump
# version 2.2.0
# http://phpwizard.net/phpMyAdmin/
# http://phpmyadmin.sourceforge.net/ (download page)
#

Comment: HELLO i have three file uploaded to my phpmyadmin does that sound right

Comment: @user1786563 I have no idea what files you should or should not upload to phpmyadmin. I verified that the mysql code is correct using the following [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bacb8). I realize this may not solve all the problems you are experiencing, but it does answer your question.