# I keep getting errors when I paste the dumpsql file

Tags: mysql

Here is the error:

```
 MySQL said: Documentation
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 9

```
CREATE TABLE `affiliate_account` (
  `accountId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `amount` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `gatewayId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`accountId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_account`
-- 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_admin`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_admin` (
  `adminId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `access` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`adminId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_admin`
-- 

INSERT INTO `affiliate_admin` VALUES (1, 'admin', 'admin', 'adminstrator', 'admin@affiliates.com', '0000-00-00', 'y', 'u');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_gateway`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_gateway` (
  `gatewayId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `formcode` text NOT NULL,
  `register` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `renew` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `upgarde` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `withdraw` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `required` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`gatewayId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_gateway`
-- 

INSERT INTO `affiliate_gateway` VALUES (1, 'PayPal', '<form action=\\"https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr\\" method=\\"post\\">\r\n<input type=\\"image\\" src=\\"https://www.paypal.com/images/x-click-but20.gif\\" border=\\"0\\" name=\\"submit\\" alt=\\"Make payments with PayPal - it\\''s fast, free and secure!\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"cmd\\" value=\\"_xclick-subscriptions\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"business\\" value=\\"larrywcockerham@gmail.com\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"item_name\\" value=\\"Membership\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"item_number\\" value=\\"01\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"no_shipping\\" value=\\"1\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"return\\" value=\\"$approve\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"cancel_return\\" value=\\"$reject\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"no_note\\" value=\\"1\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"currency_code\\" value=\\"$currency\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"a3\\" value=\\"$amount\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"p3\\" value=\\"1\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"t3\\" value=\\"M\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"src\\" value=\\"1\\">\r\n<input type=\\"hidden\\" name=\\"sra\\" value=\\"1\\">\r\n</form>', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'y', 'email');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_invite`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_invite` (
  `inviteId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sendto` text NOT NULL,
  `sendDate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `msgbody` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`inviteId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_invite`
-- 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_newsletter`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_newsletter` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `subject` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `body` text NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_newsletter`
-- 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_pages`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_pages` (
  `note` text NOT NULL,
  `about` text NOT NULL,
  `contact` text NOT NULL,
  `terms` text NOT NULL,
  `privacy` text NOT NULL,
  `faq` text NOT NULL,
  `vision` text NOT NULL
) TYPE=MyISAM;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_pages`
-- 

INSERT INTO `affiliate_pages` VALUES ('<FONT color=#0099ff size=5>&nbsp; Place your main page content here</FONT>', '<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>', '<DIV align=left><FONT color=#ff0000><STRONG>Place Your Contact Information Here:</STRONG></FONT></DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>Your (Business) Name</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>Your Snail Mail Address</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>Your Phone</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>Your Email </DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left><FONT color=#ff0000><STRONG>TIP..!!! -&nbsp;<U>Avoid Email Harvesters</U> </STRONG></FONT></DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left><FONT color=#ff0000><STRONG>by publishing your email address like this:</STRONG></FONT> </DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>name[AT]yourdomainDOTcom</DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left><FONT color=#ff0000>Delete this line but KEEP the note below&nbsp;to&nbsp;visitors:</FONT> </DIV>\r\n<DIV align=left>( Replace [AT] with @ &amp; DOT with . )</DIV>\r\n<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n', '<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n', '<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n', '<DIV><STRONG><FONT color=#ff0000>Update this page with FAQs from your Visitors and Members.</FONT></STRONG></DIV>\r\n<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n<DIV><FONT color=#00cc00>This will save you time when you dont have</FONT></DIV>\r\n<DIV><FONT color=#00cc00>to answer the same questions over and over again :-)</FONT></DIV>\r\n<DIV>&nbsp;</DIV>', '<DIV><STRONG>Tell Your Members What You Want With&nbsp;Your Membership&nbsp;Site!</STRONG></DIV>\r\n<DIV><STRONG></STRONG>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n<DIV><STRONG>What "Triggered" You Into Making This Membership Site...?</STRONG></DIV>\r\n<DIV><STRONG></STRONG>&nbsp;</DIV>\r\n<DIV><STRONG>Where Do You See This Membership 1 year from now? 3 years...</STRONG></DIV>');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_plan`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_plan` (
  `planId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `duration` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `USD` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `USD_allow` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `GBP` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `GBP_allow` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `EURO` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `EURO_allow` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `commission` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`planId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_plan`
-- 

INSERT INTO `affiliate_plan` VALUES (1, 'Free', 'Free Membership', 999, 0, 'y', 0, 'y', 0, '', 0, '2006-08-05', 'u');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_planpages`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_planpages` (
  `ppageId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `planId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ppageId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_planpages`
-- 

INSERT INTO `affiliate_planpages` VALUES (1, 'free_membership', 'Load with services and / downloads', 7, '2006-08-05', 'u');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_refference`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_refference` (
  `Id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `refferedId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `ammount` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_refference`
-- 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_renew`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_renew` (
  `renewId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `planId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`renewId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_renew`
-- 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_settings`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_settings` (
  `site_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `site_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `admin_email` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `keywords` text NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `copyright` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `manual` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `currency` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `symbol` varchar(10) NOT NULL default ''
) TYPE=MyISAM;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_settings`
-- 

INSERT INTO `affiliate_settings` VALUES ('Yourdomain Membership', 'http://unselfishmarketer.com/member/', 'yourname@yourdomain.com', 'Unselfish Marketer Membership', 'remember,commas,between,your,keywords', 'Write your description here', 'Copyright © 2006 - yourdomain.com - All Rights Reserved', 'b', 'USD', '$');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_upgrade`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_upgrade` (
  `upgradeId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `planId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`upgradeId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_upgrade`
-- 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_user`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_user` (
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `username` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `refId` int(20) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `state` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `zip` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `country` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `planId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `expdate` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `ip` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `pament_type` varchar(10) NOT NULL default '',
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `Paypal` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `Stormpay` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `2Checkout` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `Nochecx` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`userId`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_user`
-- 

INSERT INTO `affiliate_user` VALUES (1, 'demo', 'demo', 0, 'JayKay', 'unselfishmarketer@gmail.com', '', '', '', '', 'Thailand', 4, '2006-08-26', '2006-07-27', '62.107.222.143', 'u', 'USD', '', 'unselfishmarketer@gmail.com', '', '', '');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_verification`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_verification` (
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `randomcode` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `ip` varchar(200) NOT NULL default ''
) TYPE=MyISAM;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_verification`
-- 


-- --------------------------------------------------------

-- 
-- Table structure for table `affiliate_withdraw`
-- 

CREATE TABLE `affiliate_withdraw` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  `amount` float NOT NULL default '0',
  `required` varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
  `date` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `status` char(1) NOT NULL default '',
  `gateway` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

-- 
-- Dumping data for table `affiliate_withdraw`
--
```

Note:  This is the second script that I've had this problem with.  They are older scripts that I assume have been around for years.

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Comment: Trying using `ENGINE = MyISAM`

Comment: This is certainly a duplicate (although not entirely of that linked above, which isn't specifically to do with dump files); but not "too localized".  Voting to reopen in favour of a more accurate closure reason.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html):

> #### Note
>
> The older `TYPE` option was synonymous with `ENGINE`. `TYPE` was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5. *When upgrading to MySQL 5.5 or later, you must convert existing applications that rely on `TYPE` to use `ENGINE` instead.*