# MySQL Version Related Syntax Errors

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, mysql-error-1064

When uploading a SQL script using MySQL version 5.5.23-55 and importing using phpMyadmin version 3.4.11.1, I am getting the following goofy errors:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `dp_banks` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `owner` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `bname` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `baddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `bcity` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `bzip` varchar(16) NOT NULL default '',
  `bcountry` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `bstate` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `bphone` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `bnameacc` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `baccount` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `btype` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `brtgnum` varchar(9) NOT NULL default '',
  `bswift` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `default` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

MySQL said:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1' at line 19`

Researching on the net, I found an article that recommended changing `TYPE=MyISAM` to `ENGINE=MyISAM`. Making this change now gives the following errors:

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE `dp_confirms` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `newuser` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newpass` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newquestion` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `newanswer` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `newmail` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `newfname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newlname` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newcompany` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `newregnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newdrvnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newaddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `newcity` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `newcountry` char(2) NOT NULL default '',
  `newstate` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newzip` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
  `newphone` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `newfax` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
  `sponsor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `confirm` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  `cdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `newuser` (`newuser`),
  KEY `newmail` (`newmail`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

MySQL said:

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`), UNIQUE KEY`newuser`(`newuser`), KEY ' at line 22`

Thanks in advance for all help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than changing `TYPE` to `ENGINE`  change

```
  `cdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
                   ^^^^
```

to

```
  `cdate` timestamp NOT NULL,
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f56a)** demo

Answer (score 0):

```
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Replace this with

```
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

Type has been replaced with [engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html).

TYPE keyword is depreciated (since 5.0) and not supported in MySQL5.5 (and I think even 5.1).  Instead of TYPE keyword use ENGINE keyword.

Answer (score 0):

My experience was that i had to change two things:

> TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Replace this with

> ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

AND

> `cdate` timestamp(14) NOT NULL,

to

> `cdate` timestamp NOT NULL,

That worked for me