# Wordpress PhpMyAdmin import db error

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Im trying to move my wordpress site over to another hosting. I have exported the db and I am re-importing it onto the hosting. The database does have a different name but I have updated the file.

Here is the error I receive when trying to import it:

Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
`meta_id` bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`comment_id` bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`meta_key` varchar( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`meta_value` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY ( `meta_id` ) ,
KEY `comment_id` ( `comment_id` ) ,
KEY `meta_key` ( `meta_key` )
) TYPE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =17;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=17' at line 9

I had a look on here and a lot of people said it was because Add `CREATE PROCEDURE` / `FUNCTION` / `EVENT` statement needed ticking, but I have done this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As documented under [`CREATE TABLE` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-table.html):

> **Note**
>   The older `TYPE` option was synonymous with `ENGINE`. `TYPE` was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5. *When upgrading to MySQL 5.5 or later, you must convert existing applications that rely on `TYPE` to use `ENGINE` instead.*

Therefore, you want:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_commentmeta` (
`meta_id` bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`comment_id` bigint( 20 ) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`meta_key` varchar( 255 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
`meta_value` longtext,
PRIMARY KEY ( `meta_id` ) ,
KEY `comment_id` ( `comment_id` ) ,
KEY `meta_key` ( `meta_key` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT =17;
```

Comment: I did this but received a different error 'TYPE=MyISAM  AUTO_INCREMENT=9' at line 22

Comment: @user2648610: Then you'll need to change it on line 22 as well; indeed, every use of `TYPE` will have to be changed for `ENGINE`.