# Syntax error creating table

Tags: mysql

When i try to create table using the below code,

```
CREATE TABLE `audit` (
  `audit_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `datestamp` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `message_number` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`audit_id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=196 ;
```

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8'

Can someone help me to rectify the error?

Thanks

Comment: maybe `ENGINE=MyISAM`

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Answer (score 3):

yes... use ENGINE instead TYPE like this

```
CREATE TABLE `category` (
 `category_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `department_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
 `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
 `description` varchar(200) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`category_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```