# create table with mysql and set TYPE=InnoDB in the sql string

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to create a mysql table with this code:

```
create table geodb_type_names (
  type_id              integer not null,
  type_locale          varchar(5) not null,
  name                 varchar(255) not null,             /* varchar(500)? */
unique (type_id, type_locale)
) TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

It comes from a mysql dump for OpenGeoDb.

So I didn't create it by myself.
If I include this statement in phpmyadmin I get this error message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8' at line 10
```

But I can't find the issue. Maybe someone can help me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [1064 error in CREATE TABLE ... TYPE=MYISAM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428755/1064-error-in-create-table-type-myisam)

Comment: Now TYPE is not in use. Please use ENGINE in the place of TYPE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TYPE** is replaced by **ENGINE**. TYPE was deprecated in MySQL 4.0 and removed in MySQL 5.5.

Use this query:

```
create table geodb_type_names (
  type_id              integer not null,
  type_locale          varchar(5) not null,
  name                 varchar(255) not null,             /* varchar(500)? */
unique (type_id, type_locale)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it in view minutes.